# Why does Ember.js require a server?

Tags: ember.js

I've downloaded Ember.js ver 1.13.13 for a test drive.
With other js frameworks, I am able to run from a file system. Does Ember require a server? I could not run directly from a file system. I did find some old tutorials that allows this. Is this a new thing?

Comment: Ember doesn't require a server. It's just a Javascript framework, if you can load it into the browser it will run. What didn't work when you tried?

Comment: That was my expectation. But, after creating an app using "ember new" command, I could not run the app/indx.html directly from the file system as I expected. If I run "ember server" command, I can open the index.html via localhost:4200/index.html. This is different then when I tried the version from last year.

Comment: The generated project requires a server because there's really no reason to have a project *not* use a server. Your use case just isn't very common. You can still use Ember without a server you just won't be able to use the code generation tools of Ember CLI, you'll have to start the project from scratch (just like you did when you used it previously).

Comment: Thanks for the info. The case I had in mind was to use ember.js to create a mobile app. I have already created one using backbone and PhoneGap, which is the app store now. I was checking out ember for another project. In these cases, there is no server (for serving client code anyways. It uses web api for data). all the code is installed in the mobile device wrapped in PhoneGap.

Comment: Using the ember build command will generate index.html in the dist directory, which you can open directly without a server.

Comment: @Gaurav, that's perfect! Exactly what I wanted as a result. Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [Ember-CLI](http://ember-cli.com/) which requires running `ember serve` in order to view your ember app. Ember-CLI uses conventions so that it knows where to locate the files that compose your ember app. As Ember-CLI locates your files, it knows how to combine them in a manner that ultimately results in the single JavaScript file that is executed in your browser. In theory you could use the globals style of development-which is the style reflected in the 'old tutorials' that you reference-and run the app directly without using any sort of "server." But, I don't recommend that. Learning Ember-CLI is useful as it is the preferred method of development moving forward. And, in my opinion, gives you a number of features that allow you to more quickly prototype apps. You can read more about that in the link I provided to the Ember-CLI website.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I wonder if there is a way to get the generated single JS file? Sort of like a "compiled" code. That would be perfect for what I'm trying to do, which is to build a mobile app using PhoneGap.

Comment: Yes - if you run `ember build --environment=production` Ember-CLI will produce a minified version of the JavaScript that you can use.